# "An error occurred while extracting files." using Archive Manager

Tags: archive, administration

I get this error while extracting files with Archive Manager:

> An error occurred while extracting files

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What files? Is there a rar file and a bunch of numbered files? If so I found I must choose the ,rar file.

Comment: I am trying to install vmWare it has bunch of files but i cannot execute any of them @David

Comment: You only answered part of my question.

Comment: NO it is not rar files

Answer (score 4):

I think what would be the easiest for you to do is try this from the command line.

99% of the time the archiver works normally, but when you run into issues using the terminal is easier. Go into the directory with the archive through the file explorer and right click an empty space in the folder. select open terminal here.

Now you should do an `ls -lia` to list all the files in this directory.

If you do not see file names, just do a `file filename.tar.gz`, for example, to see what kind of files you are dealing with. We do need this information to help you further.

Depending on what file it is, if they are archives, you can use for example:

```
unzip file.zip
gunzip file.gz
tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
```

If they are `.deb` files, they need to be run with `sudo dpkg -i package_filename.deb`

*Or* right click → open with Software Center.

If they are `.sh` files, they are shell script files.
You can right click the file and then go to permissions tab. Check the box for allowing it to be executed. And then do a `./filename.sh`  to execute the script.

Comment: Yes, this is the best way. But doesn't this nondescript error message make Archive Manager completely unusable? I just got the same dialogs on multiple GB-large archives I tried to unpack on my new laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. The Archive Manager has a "Test integrity" option, but this too gives the same dialog, no log file of what the error is!

Comment: I created an issue on the project to ask for error log viewing in UI: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/-/issues/181

Comment: I agree that a lot of the GU Interfaces on Linux can use some work :) I think there are other archive and file managers you can try as alternative tho!